# Why I cannot access Openstack Metadata Service?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have `kolla-ansible openstack ussuri` cluster . It used to works well. Accidently, the metadata service cannot be accessed by instance.   The keypair in openstack not imported to the instance. I checked the instance log. I found this warning:
`[WARNING]: No active metadata service found`
I checked the `neutron_metadata_agent` is running.
I tried `curl http://169.254.169.254/openstack` from running instance that has been created before this issue

```
ubuntu@test-vm:~$ curl http://169.254.169.254/openstack
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Connection refused
```

here is the ip route inside the instance

```
ubuntu@test-vm:~$ ip ro
default via 172.30.0.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 172.30.255.102 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 172.30.255.3 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 172.30.255.102 metric 100 
172.30.0.0/16 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.255.102
```

Could somebody help me out? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The actual metadata service is hosted by the `Nova API`. It listens on `port 8775/TCP` either directly or there is a separate `vhost` configuration if `Apache` is used as e.g. `TLS` proxy. The `Neutron` metadata agent just acts as kind of forwarder between the instance and the actual metadata service.

[This graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4MdX.jpg) depicts the communication flow (for Train though, but probably still the same for Ussuri).

I suggest to check whether `Nova API` is still listening to `port 8775/TCP` and if so, try to debug the communication flow in the [graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4MdX.jpg). Also check the security group of your instance. Maybe your default security group is broken.

Comment: thank you for the information. it solved by create new dhcp agent and remove the old one, so neutron recreate new connection between my internal network to 169.254.169.254